# Redirect Users to different pages based on authentication

Tags: asp.net, redirect, linkbutton

I am using asp `LinkButton` in my masterpage and I would like to direct users to different pages based on whether they are anonymous(unauthenticated) or they are authenticated.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="HomeLink" runat="server" onclick="HomeLink_Click">
    Home
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Problem with this is, I have never used this control before, and msdn doesn't provide a clear answer on how to do so.

Please help me with a sample code i could use in my code behind file.

Comment: sorry about the code i provided, here is the right code:

<asp:LinkButton ID="HomeLink" runat="server" onclick="HomeLink_Click">Home</asp:LinkButton>

Comment: Remember that you can edit again your owm posts to improve them at any time. This surely needs you  to provide more information and focus more on what are you looking for

Comment: Have you written any code for HomeLink_Click() function ? Are you making use of Session variables in your code? If yes then what do those look like ?